# Unable to setup Rspec & Capybara in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, capybara, rspec-rails

I am creating a sample application for rspec testing, and I followed the below steps
**In Gemfile:**

```
gem "rspec-rails", :group => [:test, :development]
group :test do
  gem "factory_girl_rails"
  gem "capybara"
  gem "guard-rspec"
end
```

**Then executed the below steps:**

1. bundle.
2. rails g rspec:install.
3. mkdir spec/support spec/models spec/routing.

**Added "require capybara/rspec" to my spec_helper file**

**Created a sample test as below:**

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "Users" do
  describe " List users" do
    it "List all users" do
      get users_path
      page.has_content?('List Users')
    end
  end
end
```

but it doesn't work, getting the below error

---

```
undefined local variable or method `page'
```

*** I suspect that I was not configured the capybara properly, Let me know the proper way to configure the capybara.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got working after including the capybara dsl to spec helper

```
config.include Capybara::DSL
```

Comment: Please accept this answer if it was your solution.  My opinion is that in order to conform to what Capybara 2.0 and RSpec are expecting in the structure of your **spec/** directory, you'd be better off revising your configuration; have a look at the two links in my answer for details.

Answer (score 9):

Since you didn't specify a version for Capybara in your **Gemfile**, I assume you've got version `>= 2.0`, which means that any tests that use `page` should go under a **spec/features** directory.

Have a look at the following links for more information:

- [rspec-rails and capybara 2.0: what you need to know](http://alindeman.github.com/2012/11/11/rspec-rails-and-capybara-2.0-what-you-need-to-know.html)
- [rspec-rails gem Capybara page](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/Capybara.md)

If you don't want to use a **spec/features** directory, you should be able to mark a test as a `feature` in the following way:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "Users" do
  describe " List users", type: :feature do
    it "List all users" do
      get users_path
      page.has_content?('List Users')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: moving my test files from spec/requests -> spec/features worked for me. no more error on visit. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its worth checking out the new Capybara DSL for integration tests (note the features directory):

```
# spec/features/user_list_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

feature 'User list' do
  scenario 'List all users' do
    visit users_path
    expect(page).to have_content 'List Users'
  end
end
```

I wrote a blog post with some detailed information on [End-to-end testing with RSpec integration tests and Capybara](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/33771089985/rspec-integration-tests-with-capybara) using RSpec 2.0 expect syntax, along with Capybara DSL for `feature/scenarios`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just add this to your spec_helper.rb:

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
```