# Rspec have_selector error when expected output is correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails, railstutorial.org

I have 3 rspec selector fails when they all should be successes.  I'm following along with the rails-tutorial.org book and his shows as correct.

```
PagesController GET 'home' should have the right title
     Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Ruby on Rails     Sample App | Home")
       expected following output to contain a <title>Ruby on Rails Sample App | Home</title> tag:
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
   <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home</title>
   </head>
```

and the exact same errors with 'content' and 'about'

**application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
</head>
<body>
    <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

**home.html.erb**

```
    <h1>Sample App</h1>
    <p>
    This is the home page for the <a href='http://railstutorial.org'>Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a> sample application
    </p>
```

**application_helper.erb**

```
module ApplicationHelper

#Return a title on a per-page basis
def title
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    if @title.nil?
        base_title
    else
        "#{base_title} | #{@title}"
        end
    end
end
```

**pages_controller_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PagesController do
  render_views

  describe "GET 'home'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'home'
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'home'
      response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Ruby on Rails Sample App |     Home")
    end

    it "should have a non-blank body" do
      get 'home'
      response.body.should_not =~ /<body>\s*<\/body>/
    end
  end
```

Comment: What version of Capybara does your Gemfile say you are using.  If you're on version `>= 2.0`, you won't be able to see the `title` attribute, so for the tutorial's sake, specifically set the version at `1.1.2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using Capybara `2.0`, invisible text like the `title` element is ignored.  See the Capybara Github issue about it [here](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/863).

Rails Tutorial specifically uses Capybara version `1.1.2`, so if you haven't done so, make sure you write explicit versions for all your gems as per [the tutorial Gemfile](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed/blob/master/Gemfile).

If you want to use Capybara 2.0, either now or in the future, see the following SO questions for assistance setting it up, as well as getting tests for the `title` element working again:

- [Unable to setup Rspec & Capybara in Rails 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028247/567863)
- [RSpec & Capybara 2.0 tripping up my have_selector tests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13573525/567863)

Answer (score 2):

With Capybara 2.x, in order to find/interact with invisible text, you can pass ":visible => false".

Example:

```
page.should have_selector("head title", text: "my title", visible: false)
```

This applies to all content, not just title. So while yes there is a has_title() matcher for title specifically, if you need to interact with a page's hidden contents in other ways, use ":visible => false".

```
page.should have_selector("link href='style.css'", visible: false)
```

This also works with Capybara commands such as fill_in(), click_button(), etc.

```
click_button("hidden_button_name", visible: false)

fill_in("hidden_field_name", with: "foo", visible: false)
```

Confirmed using Capybara 2.2.0 and Rspec-Rails 2.14.0.

Interacting with hidden elements may be a sign that your specs are doing more than they should, but that's a separate issue. If you find your specs are breaking since you upgraded Capybara, passing in ":visible => false" to the failing specs may help get your build green.

p.s. Above hash syntax works if you are using Ruby 1.9+. If you are still on 1.8+, use ":visible => false", ":with => 'foo'", etc.