# Updated to Capybara 2.1.0.rc, now having trouble with current_path in my feature specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, capybara, acceptance-testing

So it seems like I've used `current_path` many times in `request specs`. However, Capybara now requires specs to be in the `features directory` in order to use the `Capybara DSL (page & visit)`

```
# creating_posts_spec.rb

require "spec_helper"

feature "creating posts" do

  scenario "creating posts with valid info is successful" do
    visit new_post_path
    fill_in 'Title', with: "This is a title test"
    fill_in 'Content', with: "This is a content test"
    click_button 'Create Post'
    page.should have_content 'Post was successfully created.'
    page.current_path.should == post_path(post)
  end
end
```

Its a simple post controller and the page lands on show after the post is rendered just fine in the browser.

```
 posts GET    /posts(.:format)               posts#index
                     POST   /posts(.:format)               posts#create
            new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)           posts#new
           edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)      posts#edit
                post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#show
                     PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#update
                     DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#destroy
                root        /                              posts#index
```

Why am i getting an error: `undefined local variable or method 'post'`?

I just don't remember ever having this trouble.
Anyone have a suggestion or reason? or am I missing something obvious? It's late

Comment: Does the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028247/unable-to-setup-rspec-capybara-in-rails-3-2 work?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I've been through all that and `page` works fine. Its only the `current_path` line. It's strange unless I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `post` *is* undefined.... You don't set it anywhere in the entire scenario.

Comment: If you clear out your db every time, you could probably get by with something like `post_path(1)`, to save the lookup and keep your tests fast.

Comment: Your right, I should have done something like `post = Post.find_by_title("This is a title test")`. I knew I was missing something obvious.

Comment: I guess the feature specs have a different feel to them. I was thinking something like you just proposed and were right about, looked more like request specs. Anyway, Thanks for your help